# withFile closing file to early

Tags: file, haskell, io, lazy-evaluation

After running following code

```
withFile "file.txt" ReadWriteMode 
  (\h -> hGetContents h >>= putStrLn >> hGetContents h >>= putStrLn)
```

I get contents of `file.txt` printed only once and then I receive following exception:

`*** Exception: file.txt: hGetContents: illegal operation (handle is closed)`

Why did Haskell close the file so early that I could not execute all desired actions? The documentation says

> The Handle will be automatically closed ***when the computation returns***.

which seems not to be true in this case.

Why does it behave like this and how to chain multiple IO operations on single handler?

Comment: That's what the `withFile` documentation says, but `hGetContents` also has some documentation. "Computation `hGetContents hdl` returns the list of characters corresponding to the unread portion of the channel or file managed by `hdl`, which is put into an intermediate state, semi-closed. Any operation that fails because a handle is closed, also fails if a handle is semi-closed."

Answer (score 4):

`hGetContents` puts the file handle into the "semi-closed" state. All explicit operations on that handle are invalid after this point. This has nothing to do with `withFile`; you just can't use `hGetContents` on the same handle twice.

In general, you want to *either* use lazy I/O throughout (with `readFile` for example), *or* use explicit I/O throughout (using `withFile` and friends). Preferably the latter. Trying to mix the two will probably just result in problems.

In general, lazy I/O is good for quick prototyping, but does have quite a lot of drawbacks in terms of predicting when the underlying OS resources will be released.

Comment: Ok, but what if I would like to read file and then write to it without reopening it?

Comment: @Ikciwor In that case, you *definitely* want to avoid lazy I/O. Open the file with `withFile`, and use `hGetChar` or `hGetLine` repeatedly to read in the contents, and `hPutChar` or `hPutLine` to write data back. (If you want to overwrite rather than append, you'll need to `hSeek` back to the beginning before writing.)